# Excel hyperlink to specific row in workbook based on cell vale in original workbook

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I have 2 workbooks where a stock symbol is in the first column of each workbook.  I've created a column in workbook A next to the column of the stock symbols, where I want insert a hyperlink that will reference the stock symbol in the column next to it in workbook A, and take you to the corresponding row in workbook B that has that same stock symbol.  I can't seem to get the syntax correct.

This is what I have so far:
=HYPERLINK("[file_location]Sheet2!",)
I don't know the syntax to reference a cell from the original sheet and look it up in the destination sheet

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add some screenshot with sample data of both the sheets with row and column numbers and mention file and sheet names.

Answer (score 0):

If in WorkBook A you have Stock Symbols in A2:A10 and in WorkBook B in anywhere in column A then enter following formula in B2 of WorkBook A and copy if down.

```
=HYPERLINK("[C:\Users\naresh\Desktop\Book100.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$"&MATCH(A2,[Book100.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$A,0),A2)
```

`C:\Users\naresh\Desktop` is my desktop folder path and `Book100.xlsx]Sheet1` is WorkBook B in your case. Edit accordingly. Note that the WorkBook B needs to be opened for the link to work. Link will take you to the first symbol match in WorkBook B.